# Error in recoding function from package epicalc

Tags: r

I am trying to use `recode` function for demarcation of value in a variable but am not able to do so with a specific variable only where as it is working fine for another variable.

```
recode(age, age > 60, NA)
```

> Error in recode.default(age, age > 60, NA) : object '.data' not found

[image: With out any error]

[image: Giving error]

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could just do

```
age[age>60] <- NA
```

Note that [epicalc is somewhat obsolete ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32316360/why-was-package-epicalc-removed-from-cran). It looks like epicalc operates by default on a [data frame called .data](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/epicalc/html/recode.html), which could make things difficult ...

Comment: Thanks @Ben for your help. I can now do what i want but i am still confused on why its working on one data frame and not in another! It will be great if you can share a bit on this. Thanks again.